# token_uri starts with 'ar://" , how do fetch?

Tags: nft, react

I'm using react to get nft metadata, I came across an nft 'token_uri' starting with 'ar://'. How do I unpack this?

`token_uri: ar://eXcwlbsV1BiRGCsGKXa60Mj0i-xDZU0k95l_ysNwv_w/1.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ar refers to the arweave host. You can access the metadata by simply inserting "arweave.net/${hash/1.json}"

Link to it: https://arweave.net/eXcwlbsV1BiRGCsGKXa60Mj0i-xDZU0k95l_ysNwv_w/1.json